# Franck-Condon principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals

I am having trouble understanding the [Franck-Condon principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franck%E2%80%93Condon_principle) for radiative transitions and would be very thankful for any help.
Why do we have multiple different wave functions for the exact same energy level (the lower potential ist referred to as E0 and the upper as E1)? Why is the upper potential shifted to the right?

[image: Franck-Condon (Source: wikipedia)]

Comment: Just FYI, if you found an answer satisfactory you should mark it with the check symbol to let everyone know your issue is resolved! If an answer does not satisfy you but you still solved it, you can always answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR for the first part: This diagram is illustrating two types of energy states: the electronic energies, represented as the black enveloping curves, and the vibrational energies, represented as horizontal lines in the electronic states with the wave functions drawn on top of them. The vibrational levels are typically drawn inside of the relevant electronic potential energy surface (the curve showing how the electronic energy changes as a function of internuclear distance) like this. Transitions between electronic and vibrational levels simultaneously are part of [the study of vibronic spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibronic_spectroscopy).

The reason this sort of diagram can be made is that in the Born-Oppenheimer approximation the molecular Hamiltonian is separated into terms corresponding only to the electrons and only the nuclei, $\hat{H} \approx \hat{H}_e + \hat{H}_n$. This allows us to solve the Schrödinger equation for the electrons with the nuclear positions "clamped" at a particular geometry, and then to repeat this ad nauseam until we have a complete picture of how the electronic energy varies for the various possible molecular geometries. This potential energy surface becomes the potential energy used in solving the Schrödinger equation for the molecular vibrational states of the nuclei. When the Hamiltonian is separated this way we can also represent the total wave function as a product of the constituent parts: $|\Psi\rangle \approx |\psi_e\rangle |\psi_n\rangle$. What you see drawn as orange waves are pictures of $|\psi_n\rangle$ for many different values of the vibrational quantum number $\nu$, where the prime and double prime just tell you which electronic states the vibrational levels belong to. The unfortunate old convention is to use a double prime for the ground electronic state and a single prime for the excited electronic state. The electronic wave function not shown here would look like a molecular orbital of some sort. A given energy state of the system thus constructed is the electronic energy at the minimum plus the energy of the corresponding vibrational level that is occupied.

TLDR for the second part: The upper potential energy surface is shifted to the right simply because the geometric energy minimum is not identical for different electronic states. In other words, the typical bond length in the ground state need not be the same as the typical bond length in the excited state! The shapes (depth, spread, etc.) of the potential energy surface need not be similar either. Very often, the excited electronic energy wells are shallower, allowing easier dissociation of a bond. See, for instance, [this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed057p101).

The positioning of the energetic minima is actually quite important in spectroscopy. As this figure shows, the lowest energy vibrational state is typically in a relatively "harmonic," or parabolic part of the potential energy surface, at least for stretching vibrations. This means that the maximum of the ground vibrational wave function is roughly centered over the minimum energy on the potential energy surface. But remember I said earlier that the minima for different electronic states do not necessarily line up. This means that the vibrational wave functions that will have the maximum overlap are not necessarily the ground state wave functions! A very rough rule of thumb is that if you draw a vertical line from the minimum of the ground state potential surface up to the excited state potential surface, then the vibrational state with maximum overlap will have an energy relatively near the point you reached on the on the excited electronic state curve, as shown above. The overlap is critical, as you can show from [Fermi's Golden Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule) that the transition probability is proportional to the square of the transition dipole momentum integral $P_{1\leftarrow 0}\propto |\langle \Psi_1 | \hat{\mu} |\Psi_0 \rangle | ^2$. After some tedious expanding and simplifying with the Born-Oppenheimer approximation, the Franck-Condon factor for the transition probability is obtained,
\begin{gather*}
P_{1\leftarrow 0}\propto |\langle \psi_{\nu^{\prime\prime}} |\psi_{\nu^\prime} \rangle |^2
\end{gather*}
where the quantum numbers label the relevant wavefunctions as on the figure above. In other words, the overlap of the vibrational wave functions is the key determinant in the transition probability between vibronic (vibrational and electronic) states. If you were to calculate the overlap of these wave functions, you might obtain a result like the following I obtained for molecular iodine,
[image]